# Is there any way of using Google mail "internally" whilst on same domain as O365?

Tags: email, gmail, office365, google-workspace

We (the educational establishment I work for) use Office365 for e-mail.

We recently set up a Google Apps for Education account on the same domain, to use with students, and we didn't really think we'd need e-mail access.

However, we've since learnt that it would be useful to have access to e-mails for notification purposes, e.g. when homework tasks are set/fed back on.

At the moment, our students have addresses like `username@domain.com` and staff have `firstname.lastname@domain.com`. These are the same formats that we use on our Office365 accounts (which some, but not all, students have access to for Office Pro Plus).

Is there any way of setting our Google Apps domain up so that Gmail only tries to send to itself? At the moment, if I send an e-mail to a colleague from my Google account, they will receive it in O365. I would like Gmail to only ever send to other Google accounts, especially when sending feedback notifications etc. If I send an e-mail from Google to a colleague, I'd want it to go to their Google account - not O365.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Potentially_ you could set your own EAC rules to forward/redirect emails to another SMTP address - would this be feasible?

Comment: Even if somehow possible, I would not recommend doing this. It will create a lot of unnecessary confusion. There should be a 1:1 association between e-mail addresses and mailboxes.

Answer (score -1):

Point your MX records to Gmail from your domain's panel.

Below are the MX records of Gmail with their priority (1 being the highest priority)

```
1           ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5           ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5           ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10          ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10          ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
```

First add these records then delete the old records.

Note: Don't change the priorities or add any other records apart from these.

Just in case here is a link on how to change the records:

https://in.godaddy.com/help/change-an-mx-record-19235

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question I've asked. Wouldn't this just overwrite the O365 records I have? We still want to continue using O365 as our main e-mail provider, we just want to also be able to use Gmail internally (e.g. at domain.com to at domain.com and nothing else).